# how to populate dropdown box in gridview in edit mode?

Tags: c#

i have loaded input country dropdown at the time of data insertion.
 
                        Select..
                        Afghanistan
                        Aland Islands
                        Albania
                        Algeria

now i m showing that data in gridview and want to edit that data too.
for that i need to populate that whole list of country again.
how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill your `DropDownList` control in the [DridView.RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/editable_gridview_control.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an asp.net question.  You can load the data on the control's Load() event.  Just add the event and when it fires, load the data for it.